# 99 percentile on BBG Government Generic Bonds

Tags: price, yield

I want to calculate 5 day price moves using 10 years of historical data to a 99% confidence level. I have downloaded 10years of yields and converted into price by subtracting the yield from 100 (par). I have then calculated a series of 5 day price moves and then calculated using the excel percentile function. Am I missing something? My colleague is saying I should use modified duration (Duration x Yield change). i am sceptical as my thought is that using 10 years of historic data captured the price sensitivity. I would appreciate someone's feedback

Comment: "converted into price by subtracting the yield from 100" would you be willing to trade at that price?

Comment: No I would not as the price need to factor in the present value of future payments. I am struggling though as to whether this has already been factored into the BBG generic bond as they are made up be a number of real ISIN's with different coupons

Comment: Yes indeed, if multiple bonds have the same yield, but different coupons, and you used the yield to  discount their future cash flows, would you expect the prices to come out the same?